# How to handle tables created at runtime with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, runtime, hbm

I need to create tables at runtime based on the classname of an *Object* my tool receives in input.
e.g. if I receive an instance of the class *User* (with fields firstname, lastname, address) I have to create a table for that class (with column firstname, lastnam and address); now on, everytime my tool receives a *User* instance in input, it will have to refer to the table just created.
If, instead, the tool receives an instance of the class *Software* (with fields name, type, description) it have to create a new table for that class (with columns name, type and description; and so on...

The problem is not the creation of the table, but the mapping of such table with a Java Class through Hibernate, of course without write any handmade hbm file.

Does someone have any idea on how to handle such situation ( maybe through reflection? ).

Thank you.

Comment: You mean if you receive input(firstname,lastname and address) you will create user object and save it. However if you receive input(name, type, description) you will create Software object and save it. Am i right? Please correct me if something is missing or wrong.

Comment: Hibernate is not intended to be used like that.  You need to define all your Entities in advance, then hibernate can create them in necessary.

Comment: @AshutoshJha not exactly, I have to create a Table on the DB (named following a custom naming strategy)

Comment: @EssexBoy I know that hibernate is not intended to be used like that.. If so, i would be simpler :) but I really need to use it like that...

Answer (score 1):

In that case if you want to create class on runtime, then take a look at 
[this](http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial). Might help.